# Place query results in different divs

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to display query's results in my view in different divs, I've spend the day reading on [ellislab](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) how to display results if I have understand correctly result() function return an object, this is my model:

**model**

```
function get_post(){
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->order_by('date_time', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(2);
    $results = $this->db->get('post');

    if($results->num_rows()<1){
          return false;
    }
    else{
          return $results->result();
    }
}
```

And this is what my controller does:

**controller**

```
foreach($results as $res){
    $data['post_signature']     =  $res->signature;
    $data['post_title']         =  $res->title;
    $data['post_article']       =  $res->article;
    $data['post_date']          =  date('d-M-Y', strtotime($res->date_time));
    $data['post_time']      =  date('H:i', strtotime($res->date_time));
}
```

What i would like to show in my view is the series of results in a div and the second in another div.

```
<div id="1">First Result</div>
<div id="2">Second Result</div>
```

What I tought to do was to pass the whole query result to the view and use a foreach, like this:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $res)
     <div id="1">First Result</div>
     <div id="2">Second Result</div>
?>
```

Obviously the problem to this approach is that this foreach just reduplicate both the divs and I just want to put the first result in the first div and the second in the second div. I also tought about changing the foreach into the controller and use a for statement to save all the parameters returned into the data array, but for some reasons this seems very inefficient.

I hope you have better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your `$results` object to the view and use a `foreach` there:

```
// in your view (assuming you passed the $results as-is
<?php
foreach ($results as $res)
{
    echo '<div id="' . $res->id . '">';
    echo $res->title . '<br />';
    echo 'Posted ' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime($res->date_time)) . ' ';
    echo 'at ' . date('H:i', strtotime($res->date_time)) . '<br />';
    echo '<p>' . $res->article . '</p>';
    echo '</div>'; 
}
/**
you'll get something like the following
<div id="1">
    My Title<br />
    Posted 14 Jan 2012 at 16:40<br />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
    Another Title<br />
    Posted 14 Jan 2012 at 16:45<br />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet also.</p>
</div>
*/
```

The idea is that `$results` is a collection of result objects, so when you loop through them in the controller (like your example in the question) - you're not getting the "collection" of objects in the view. Looping through the view allows you to manage the collection (and also the display) of those results.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing it to

```
<?php
  $i=1;
  foreach ($results as $res) {
     echo '<div id="'.$i++.'">'.$res.'</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Uuuum, `$res` is iterable-type data, right?  That can't be echo'ed.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach part is not correct. You must separate the php/html code.

Maybe you can try something like this in your view :

```
<?php foreach ($results as $key => $res) {
     echo '<div id="'.$key.'">'.implode(' ', $res).'</div>';
}
?>
```